# Обязательно ли нужна запятая

Tags: пунктуация

*Сегодня я приготовлю огромную рыбу, весом 20 кг.*

Запятая нужна, так как перед определяемым словом *рыбу* уже есть согласованное определение *огромную*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая нужна, но не потому, что есть согласованное определение перед определяемым словом, а потому, что это явное уточнение:

*Сегодня я приготовлю огромную рыбу, (какую именно огромную?) весом 20 кг*.

Но и в данном случае автор имеет право не обособлять определение, если сочтёт определения неоднородными (размер и вес) и прочитает без паузы: *Сегодня я приготовлю огромную рыбу весом 20 кг.* Тогда согласованное определение **огромную** будет относиться к сочетанию **рыбу весом 20 кг**. Это тоже будет верно.

Comment: Ну, насколько я знаю, здесь не будет хорошим тоном писать без запятой. Все же есть правило, что из-за впереди стоящего согласованного определения несогласованное обособляется

Comment: В качестве примеров (без обособления).  Ему удалось поймать белую акулу весом 1537 кг и длиной 5,24 метра. 30-летний рыбак в одиночку боролся с огромным голубым тунцом весом почти в полтонны. Вчера утром житель деревни Карала Тийт Юулик поймал на Сааремаа гигантскую щуку весом 9,07 кг и длиной 105 см.

Comment: В целом обособление несогласованных определений менее категорично, нежели обособление согласованных определений. Оно происходит в том случае, если в данном контексте требуется выделить какой-либо признак, усилить выражаемое им значение. Обособление несогласованных определений, выраженных существительным, часто является не обязательным, а факультативным.

Comment: В художественной речи они чаще обособляются, в разговорном стиле и газетной публицистике нет. У нас как раз разговорный стиль.